# NodeJS, Express, & Mongoose: Calls are intermittantly slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a really simple nodeJS app. For some reason, the response times of the server vary greatly.

Here's my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var Models = require('./schema/schema.js');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var start = Date.now();

    res.on('header', function() {
        var duration = Date.now() - start;
        var time = Date.now() - req.start;

        fs.appendFile("times.txt", time+"\n", function (err) {});

    });
    next();
});
app.use(app.router);



app.get("/tags", function(req, res) {
    var query = Models.Tag.find({}).sort({'popularity': -1}).limit(200);
    query.exec(function(err, tags) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send(tags);
    });
}
```

The data is always returned correctly, but here are my response times, as measured by the 'header' function:

```
19
11
13
6
10
10
8
9
2
62449
57862
24919
9975
11
17
21116
10
3
2
2
13
```

Most are less than 10 ms, but frequently there are some more than a minute. What is going on?

Schema:

```
var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    popularity :{
        type:Number, default:0
    },
    created_date: {
        type:Date, default:Date.now
    },
    last_update: {
        type:Date, default:Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: Is popularity indexed in your model?

Comment: No, I guess it's not. Is that a big performance hit?

Comment: No it certainly shouldn't be a big hit. That's a really bizarre pattern. My gut instinct is that there is disk IO happening for some reason, or swap files being used for the mongo hotset, but that still doesn't explain such a huge jump. How many documents are in the collection?

Comment: where is the database?on your computer?or is it a free instance on some saas?

Comment: I don't believe that this is consistent behavior or even possibly reproduce-able. This very much seems as if you are running on a virtual machine and there actually are other things happening on your actual hardware environment that are affecting the results. A working set of 200 records cannot be possibly explained otherwise.

Comment: We're having similar issues in production, same set of technologies.

Comment: I think you need to collect more information, all that you know right now is that something is slow. Check to see if any queries are slow in mongo: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/. However I'm going to have to agree with @NeilLunn, you probably are running on a shared hosting platform of some kind, even if you think you aren't.

Comment: Can you try removing the sort function and check the result? Just for the sake of debugging...

Comment: One more thing you can do for debugging is turn on deubg logging on your mongodb and check what's written to the log around the time you see slow queries.

Comment: Does the same issue show up just running the queries directly in mongo? Also, how are you connecting to mongoose? Try adding listeners to your connection to help debug: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a hosted mongo server, like mongohq, just to see if it's a local IO latency issue? A database that small shouldn't have ANY problems, unless you're doing something crazy, which you're clearly not.